# Paging a large table without postbacks in .NET MVC and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagination

I have a large table with a few million records.

Have got an MVC5 solution and using PagedList.MVC with Entity Framework I have a page showing the paged table with sorting and filters.

But every filter and page-change operation requires a postback.

Is there any way to prevent postbacks without pre-loading the entire table into memory?

Comment: Not if you want to stick with PagedList.  You need an AJAX solution and it isn't one.

Comment: I'm happy to change to a different solution. What would that be?

Comment: what do you mean by postback?  you mean full page refresh or just hitting the server?

Comment: I mean full page refresh, sorry. I have the paging working efficiently, I just don't want the page to refresh when selecting a filter, re-sorting or moving page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put in your comment you are open to a different solution why don't you do the following:

1) Assuming the large table is in some database. Update your procedure to take in as parameters, the number of rows per page in your gridview, and the current page index you are viewing in the gridview

2) Update the procedure to return only the rows for that specific page the user is on using the parameters above. Also return the total count of rows as an int this way you can calculate how many pages need to be in the gridview. Consider caching this in the session so you only need to query the total count once.

Doing this will make updating the gridview very fast since the procedure will only return the rows you need to display on the current page.

Comment: While the OP said "postback", the OP really didn't mean postback, since this is ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET WebForms.  As a result, your update panel suggestion wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer to exclude that part. I think the part of having the procedure only return the rows you need to display should still help.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I already do the paging in a similar way. The results are fast - I'm just trying to avoid a full page refresh. Sorry for calling it a "postback" - I'm still new to MVC :)